# a file is copied to a specific folder and renamed to x.txt how do i open x.txt and paste "X:"

Tags: applescript

EDIT: regulus6633 has made a script that's a lot better than my outline below, it works perfectly IF you're template file isn't completely empty (I think this caused an error originally). Thanks!

This script is supposed to (1) copy a x.txt to a specific folder rename it to new_name, (2) open it, (3) paste "new_name" in all caps, and (4) insert ":" followed by return & return. The first part is working, but I'm having trouble figuring out (2), (3) and (4). The code I've written so far is pasted below.

```
 tell application "Finder"
        display dialog "new_name_dialogue" default answer " "
        set new_name to (text returned of result)
        set Selected_Finder_Item to (folder of the front window) as text
        duplicate file "Q:x:7:n7:GTD scripting:template folder:x.txt" to "Q:X:7:SI:SIAG1"
        set Path_Of_X to "Q:X:7:SI:SIAG1:" & "x.txt" as string
        set name of file Path_Of_X to (new_name as text) & ".txt"
#[something that let's me open the file is needed here]
#[something that pastes "new_name" & ":" in ALL CAPS]
#[something that inserts two lineshifts]
    end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general since you're dealing with a txt file, you do not need to "open" the file in an application and paste in text. We can read and write to text files directly from applescript. As such we read in the text from the template file, add whatever text we want to that, and then write the new text to a new file. If you then want to open and view the new file you can do that after. I did that in the "TextEdit" section of the code.

You can see at the end of the script I have subroutines to write a text file and also to change the file name to CAPS. So try the following...

```
-- initial variables
set templateFile to "Q:x:7:n7:GTD scripting:template folder:x.txt"
set copyFolder to "Q:X:7:SI:SIAG1:" -- notice this path ends in ":" because it's a folder

-- get the new name
display dialog "new_name_dialogue" default answer ""
set newName to (text returned of result)
set newPath to copyFolder & newName

-- get the text of the template file
set templateText to read file templateFile

-- add the file name in CAPS, a colon, and 2 returns at the beginning of templateText
set capsName to upperCase(newName)
set newText to capsName & ":" & return & return & templateText

-- write the newText to newPath
writeTo(newPath, newText, text, false)

-- open the new file in textedit
tell application "TextEdit" to open file newPath



(*============== SUBROUTINES ==============*)
on writeTo(targetFile, theData, dataType, apendData)
    -- targetFile is the path to the file you want to write
    -- theData is the data you want in the file.
    -- dataType is the data type of theData and it can be text, list, record etc.
    -- apendData is true to append theData to the end of the current contents of the file or false to overwrite it
    try
        set targetFile to targetFile as text
        if targetFile does not contain ":" then set targetFile to POSIX file targetFile as text
        set openFile to open for access file targetFile with write permission
        if apendData is false then set eof of openFile to 0
        write theData to openFile starting at eof as dataType
        close access openFile
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file targetFile
        end try
        return false
    end try
end writeTo

on upperCase(theText)
    set chrIDs to id of theText
    set a to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to (count of chrIDs)
        set chrID to item i of chrIDs
        if chrID ≥ 97 and chrID ≤ 122 then set chrID to (chrID - 32)
        set end of a to chrID
    end repeat
    return string id a
end upperCase
```

Comment: wow! thanks a bunch, it's beautifully made, very readable (even for a newbie) and it JUST WORKS! (my original template file x.txt was completely empty, I had to put a line shift in it to work)

Answer (score 0):

> something that lets me open the file is needed here

```
tell application "TextEdit" to open Path_Of_X
```

---

> something that pastes `new_name` in ALL CAPS

There is a really good third party scripting addition ([Satimage OSAX](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads_osaxen.html)) that you can use for things just like this (this will only work if you've downloaded the scripting addition)...

```
set UPPER_CASE to uppercase new_name & ":"
```

---

> something that inserts two lineshifts

```
return & return
```